# How to set different values in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to add different values to this list of dictionaries.

```
empty_dict={'time':0, 'value':None}

dict=[empty_dict for i3 in range(5)]

print dict
```

O/P:

```
[{'value': None, 'time': 0}, {'value': None, 'time': 0}, {'value': None, 'time': 0}, {'value': None, 'time': 0}, {'value': None, 'time': 0}]
```

and when I set it

```
for i,i_val in enumerate(dict):
    dict[i]['value']=i

print dict

O/P: [{'value': 4, 'time': 0}, {'value': 4, 'time': 0}, {'value': 4, 'time': 0}, {'value': 4, 'time': 0}, {'value': 4, 'time': 0}]
```

^This happens, where all the values just take the last value it was set to.

I want the output to be

```
[{'value': 0, 'time': 0}, {'value': 1, 'time': 0}, {'value': 2, 'time': 0}, {'value': 3, 'time': 0}, {'value': 4, 'time': 0}]
```

I understand that there is some issue with how I am assigning values.

What am I doing wrong? And how do I achieve the output I want?

Comment: Your list comprehension is not creating 5 _new_ dictionaries. It is simply creating 5 references to the _same_ dictionary: `empty_dict`.

Comment: Ok. How do I create 5 new dictionaries?

Comment: `[{'value': i, 'time': 0} for i in range(4)]` or `[empty_dict.copy() for _ in range(4)]`. Basically, what your doing telling Python to create 5 _seperate_ dictionires, with the structure of `empty_dict`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that each of those dictionaries refer to the same object.

You need to create a copy of empty_dict. You can do this by using the dictionary constructor.  It takes another dict (in this case, your empty_dict) as an argument and returns a new dictionary.

```
empty_dict = {'time':0, 'value':None}
my_dicts = [dict(empty_dict) for i3 in range(5)]
```

Also, if you name your dict `dict`, then it will shadow the built in.

Comment: dict(empty_dict) worked, thanks. I'll set this as the answer in a bit

Comment: @lesingerouge, He'll still have to apply the for loop like he had. This will set it up so the for loop will work.

Comment: @lesingerouge This answer will work. The OP was already looping through the dictionary.

Comment: Missed the loop (and it's reason), but I agree that the issue was connected to the dict usage.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you need to do this:

```
[{'value': i, 'time': 0} for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: Didn't want to use this because my actual dictionary is pretty long, easier to encapsulate it in empty_dict

Comment: @azazelspeaks If your dictionary contains other non-primative objects embedded inside of it, my answer might not work.  In that case you'll have to use deepcopy.  ie. `import copy; my_dits = [copy.deepcopy(empty_dict) for i3 in range(5)]`